# How do I borrow a reference to what is inside an Option<T>?

Tags: rust

How do I pull a reference out of an `Option` and pass it back with the specific lifespan of the caller?

Specifically, I want to borrow a reference to a `Box<Foo>` from a `Bar` that has an `Option<Box<Foo>>` in it. I thought I would be able to do:

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&mut self) -> Result<&Box<Foo>, BarErr> {
        match self.data {
            Some(e) => Ok(&e),
            None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
        }
    }
}
```

...but that results in:

```
error: `e` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:28
   |
17 |             Some(e) => Ok(&e),
   |                            ^ does not live long enough
18 |             None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
19 |         }
   |         - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 15:54...
  --> src/main.rs:15:55
   |
15 |       fn borrow(&mut self) -> Result<&Box<Foo>, BarErr> {
   |  _______________________________________________________^ starting here...
16 | |         match self.data {
17 | |             Some(e) => Ok(&e),
18 | |             None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
19 | |         }
20 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:16:15
   |
16 |         match self.data {
   |               ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
17 |             Some(e) => Ok(&e),
   |                  - hint: to prevent move, use `ref e` or `ref mut e`
```

Hm, ok. Maybe not. It looks vaguely like what I want to do is related to [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref), like maybe I could do:

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&mut self) -> Result<&Box<Foo>, BarErr> {
        match self.data {
            Some(e) => Ok(self.data.as_ref()),
            None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
        }
    }
}
```

...but, that doesn't work either.

Full code I'm having trouble with:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar {
    data: Option<Box<Foo>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum BarErr {
    Nope,
}

impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&mut self) -> Result<&Box<Foo>, BarErr> {
        match self.data {
            Some(e) => Ok(&e),
            None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_create_indirect() {
    let mut x = Bar { data: Some(Box::new(Foo)) };
    let mut x2 = Bar { data: None };
    {
        let y = x.borrow();
        println!("{:?}", y);
    }
    {
        let z = x2.borrow();
        println!("{:?}", z);
    }
}
```

I'm reasonably sure what I've trying to do is valid here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `&mut self`.

When matching, you should match `e` as a reference. You are trying to return a reference of `e`, but the lifetime of it is only for that match statement.

```
enum BarErr {
    Nope
}

struct Foo;

struct Bar {
    data: Option<Box<Foo>>
}

impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&self) -> Result<&Foo, BarErr> {
        match self.data {
            Some(ref x) => Ok(x),
            None => Err(BarErr::Nope)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 68):

As of Rust 1.26, *match ergonomics* allows you to write:

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&mut self) -> Result<&Box<Foo>, BarErr> {
        match &self.data {
            Some(e) => Ok(e),
            None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
        }
    }
}
```

Prior to that, you can use [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref), you just need to use it earlier:

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&self) -> Result<&Box<Foo>, BarErr> {
        self.data.as_ref().ok_or(BarErr::Nope)
    }
}
```

There's a companion method for mutable references: [`Option::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut):

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Box<Foo>, BarErr> {
        self.data.as_mut().ok_or(BarErr::Nope)
    }
}
```

---

I'd encourage removing the `Box` wrapper though.

Since Rust 1.40, you can use [`Option::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) / [`Option::as_deref_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref_mut):

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&self) -> Result<&Foo, BarErr> {
        self.data.as_deref().ok_or(BarErr::Nope)
    }

    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Foo, BarErr> {
        self.data.as_deref_mut().ok_or(BarErr::Nope)
    }
}
```

Before then, I'd probably use a `map`

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&self) -> Result<&Foo, BarErr> {
        self.data.as_ref().map(|x| &**x).ok_or(BarErr::Nope)
    }

    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Foo, BarErr> {
        self.data.as_mut().map(|x| &mut **x).ok_or(BarErr::Nope)
    }
}
```

With the match ergonomics version, you can do the mapping inline:

```
impl Bar {
    fn borrow(&mut self) -> Result<&Foo, BarErr> {
        match &self.data {
            Some(e) => Ok(&**e),
            None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
        }
    }

    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Foo, BarErr> {
        match &mut self.data {
            Some(e) => Ok(&mut **e),
            None => Err(BarErr::Nope),
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer. And don't forget `as_mut`. Also, the code don't need `&mut` I think.

Comment: What's the difference between `as_ref` and `as_deref`?

Comment: @Iizuki `as_deref` is basically `.as_ref().map(Deref::deref)`