# How do you borrow a mutable reference during a match?

Tags: rust

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282117/how-do-i-borrow-a-reference-to-what-is-inside-an-optiont-in-rust) but could not get my code to work. I still have the sneaking suspicion that I need `ref` somehow.

I am trying to make a reasonable Table class in Rust to learn more about the language and running into some trouble with understanding the borrow checker and mutability concepts as well as their corresponding syntax.

I want the table class to be flexible and allow for different column types where the data types within the columns are homogeneous. So, a column of ints, floats, strings etc.

---

I started without flexible data types and came up with [this](http://is.gd/a5ezdS) hashmap mapping ints (the column labels in this case) to vectors of ints (the data within the columns).

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap; 

fn main() {
    let mut d: HashMap<isize, Vec<isize>> = HashMap::new();
    d.insert(0, Vec::new());
    d.get_mut(&0).unwrap().push(0); 

    println!("{:?}", d);
    // nice {0: [0]}
}
```

To implement flexible data types, `enum` seemed like a decent start so [that is where I started](http://is.gd/rmRJQh) but I am stuck on the implementation.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap; 

#[derive(Debug)] 
enum VT {
    A(Vec<isize>),
    B(Vec<f64>),
}

fn main() {
    let mut d: HashMap<isize, VT> = HashMap::new();
    d.insert(0, VT::A(Vec::new()));

    match d.get_mut(&0).unwrap() {
        &mut VT::A(v) => v.push(0),
        &mut VT::B(v) => v.push(0.1), // would not be reached as-is 
    } 

    println!("{:?}", d);
}
// cannot borrow immutable local variable `v` as mutable :(
```

Ultimately, having a library similar to [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) would be the dream. For now, implementing a table is good Rust practice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**From [Rust 1.26](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1260-2018-05-10) onwards**, any `&`/`ref` and `&mut`/`ref mut` pairs can be omitted, with the compiler inferring them. (This is a slightly simplistic explanation, but it’s the essence of it.)

```rust
match d.get_mut(&0).unwrap() {
    VT::A(v) => v.push(0),
    VT::B(v) => v.push(0.1),
}
```

---

**Before Rust 1.26** (from mid-2018, so any readers now are probably using a newer version), write your match block like one of these two:

```rust
match d.get_mut(&0).unwrap() {
    &mut VT::A(ref mut v) => v.push(0),
    &mut VT::B(ref mut v) => v.push(0.1),
}
```

```rust
match *d.get_mut(&0).unwrap() {
    VT::A(ref mut v) => v.push(0),
    VT::B(ref mut v) => v.push(0.1),
}
```

In patterns `ref mut` takes a mutable reference, even as `&mut` dereferences a mutable reference.

(The generally preferred convention was `match *foo { X => … }` rather than `match foo { &mut X => … }`, due to less noise on the more numerous match branch lines, but it flipped the other way after the Rust 1.26 changes, since now *that* has less noise associated with it.)