# How to get a rc::Ref<T> reference to a node pointed by a rc::Weak<RefCell<T>>?

Tags: rust, linked-list

I'm writing a linked list where there are weak references linking the previous node.

```rust
use std::cell::{Ref, RefCell, RefMut};
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

pub struct List<T> {
    head: NextLink<T>,
    tail: PrevLink<T>,
}

type NextLink<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;
type PrevLink<T> = Weak<RefCell<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    prev: PrevLink<T>,
    next: NextLink<T>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(elem: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Self {
            elem,
            prev: Weak::new(),
            next: None,
        }))
    }
}

impl<T> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            head: None,
            tail: Weak::new(),
        }
    }

    // add to tail
    pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T) {
        let new_node = Node::new(elem);
        match self.tail.upgrade().take() {
            Some(old_tail) => {
                new_node.borrow_mut().prev = Rc::downgrade(&old_tail);
                old_tail.borrow_mut().next = Some(new_node);
            }
            None => {
                self.tail = Rc::downgrade(&new_node);
                self.head = Some(new_node);
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.tail.upgrade().map(|old_tail| {
            match old_tail.borrow_mut().prev.upgrade() {
                Some(new_tail) => {
                    new_tail.borrow_mut().next = None;
                    self.tail = Rc::downgrade(&new_tail);
                }
                None => {
                    self.head.take();
                    self.tail = Weak::new();
                }
            };
            Rc::try_unwrap(old_tail).ok().unwrap().into_inner().elem
        })
    }

    // add to head
    pub fn unshift(&mut self, elem: T) {
        let new_node = Node::new(elem);
        match self.head.take() {
            Some(old_head) => {
                old_head.borrow_mut().prev = Rc::downgrade(&new_node);
                new_node.borrow_mut().next = Some(old_head);
            }
            None => {
                self.tail = Rc::downgrade(&new_node);
                self.head = Some(new_node);
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn shift(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.head.take().map(|old_head| {
            match old_head.borrow_mut().next.take() {
                Some(new_head) => {
                    new_head.borrow_mut().prev = Weak::new();
                    self.head = Some(new_head);
                }
                None => {
                    self.tail = Weak::new();
                }
            };
            Rc::try_unwrap(old_head).ok().unwrap().into_inner().elem
        })
    }

    pub fn peek_head(&self) -> Option<Ref<T>> {
        self.head
            .as_ref()
            .map(|node| Ref::map(node.borrow(), |node| &node.elem))
    }

    pub fn peek_tail(&self) -> Option<Ref<T>> {
        self.tail
            .upgrade()
            .map(|node| Ref::map(node.borrow(), |node| &node.elem))
    }

    pub fn peek_head_mut(&mut self) -> Option<RefMut<T>> {
        self.head
            .as_ref()
            .map(|node| RefMut::map(node.borrow_mut(), |node| &mut node.elem))
    }

    pub fn peek_tail_mut(&mut self) -> Option<RefMut<T>> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for List<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        while let Some(old_head) = self.head.take() {
            self.head = old_head.borrow_mut().next.take();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a compilation error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `node`
   --> src/lib.rs:106:25
    |
106 |             .map(|node| Ref::map(node.borrow(), |node| &node.elem))
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                         |        |
    |                         |        `node` is borrowed here
    |                         returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

It seems that when the weak reference of the tail node upgrades to `Rc`, this `Rc` is owned by this function, and will be consumed in the end.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Writing doubly linked list is pretty much impossible in safe rust (I might be wrong, we have Pin API, but I can't imagine it being very useful or how to implement it). I'd recommend to either think of something else, or use raw pointers, *like you would in other languages which inherently are unsafe*; contrary to popular belief, linked list isn't trivial to get right the first time and you don't write linked lists everyday. std has an implementation done in exactly that matter. https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/linked_list.rs.html#38

Comment: @Yamirui using weak pointers allows you to write a doubly-linked list in safe Rust, so your comment isn't extremely relevant. See [How do I express mutually recursive data structures in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168774/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster not any less relevant than pointless overhead for the sake of the argument of how safe rust is. Every single relevant data structure is built from the ground up on unsafe and will always be. Unsafe is a valid option, not a spook that you avoid for everything and always. Regarding what you linked, did you ignore `think of something else` on purpose? Because Arena is "something else". If anything is irrelevant here, it's your comment on mine. You can point out that "something else" to the asker without telling me that my relevant comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Your question

Use [`Weak::upgrade`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html#method.upgrade) and [`RefCell::borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow):

```
fn example<T>(foo: Weak<RefCell<T>>) {
    let strong: Rc<RefCell<T>> = foo.upgrade().unwrap();
    let the_ref: Ref<T> = strong.borrow();
}
```

## Your problem

`self.head.as_ref()` returns an `Option<&Rc<_>>`. `self.tail.upgrade()` returns an `Option<Rc<_>>`. When you call `Option::map`, ownership of the inner value is transferred to the closure, and you get the error you posted. You could call `Option::as_ref`, but the `Option` is owned by the function, so you are not allowed to return a reference because it wouldn't be valid once the `Rc` is destroyed.

The *only* thing you can do is to return the `Rc` from the function.

See also:

- [How do I borrow a reference to what is inside an Option<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22282117/155423)
- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29401626/155423)